# Restricting Textbox Entry

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

How would we restrict a Text Box in c# (Windows Form)? e.g (I have two TextBoxes `textBox1` and `textBox2`) so I `textBox2` should not accept numbers greater than `textBox1`.

For example `textBox1=100`, so `textBox2` should not accept value greater than `100`.

Comment: Use some NumericUpDown() controls instead?...

Comment: Assuming this is a form, could you try validation on form submission rather than blocking the `TextBox` from receiving a value?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event on the textbox.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

}
```

You would then need to get `textBox1`'s value and parse it to an integer.

```
int textBoxValue;
Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out textBoxValue);
```

And then check if the parsed value is below a threshold (100).  You would have to use a [conditional statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx) for this.  Since you did not provide any code in your question, I will leave this bit to you.